# JupyterLab: Unable to switch environments in Terminal Window

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, virtualenv, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm running JupyterLab on MacOS and for some reason I get the following error when trying to switch virtual environments:

```
bash-3.2$ conda activate yhoo

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
```

I'm able to execute other conda commands in the JupyterLab Terminal such as `bash-3.2$ conda env list` without error. I'm able to execute `bash-3.2$ conda activate yhoo` outside the JupyterLab Terminal in iTerm without error.  Therefore, it seems this is an issue with running Terminal via JupyterLab.  Grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The Conda `activate` command is a shell command that is typically defined through sourcing the user's shell resource file or profile (e.g., `~/.bash_profile`). The Jupyter Terminado defaults to launching not in login mode, i.e., it doesn't source the profile. Hence, it doesn't define `conda activate`, and no amount of `conda init`'ing is going to resolve it.

### Quick Fix

For *ad hoc* fix, just source your file

```bash
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This assumes `conda init` has been run at least once and this is MacOS.

### Permanent Fix

Jupyter has settings to define the shell command that Terminado launches with. If Jupyter is installed in a Conda environment, say `foo`, then the settings file will be at:

```bash
$(conda run -n foo echo \$CONDA_PREFIX)/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

And edit it to include the setting

```json
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "terminado_settings": {
      "shell_command": ["/bin/bash", "-l"]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```bash
$(conda run -n foo echo \$CONDA_PREFIX)/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

and add the setting

```python
c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = { "shell_command": ["/bin/bash", "-l"] }
```

similar to [what is noted on the Jupyter Discourse](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/customizing-shell-launched-by-terminal/3412).

Comment: Thank you.  The temporary fix worked but unfortunately the permanent fix did not.  I entered both commands and received the same error: `$ (conda run -n base echo \$CONDA_PREFIX)/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json'`

Comment: `$ (conda run -n yhoo echo \$CONDA_PREFIX)/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py'`

Comment: @jgg no space after the “$”. The `$(…)` runs a command and returns the result inline. Sorry if it wasn’t clear, but I’m just giving that as a way to generically *find* the file, not a command that does anything. If you know where your Jupyter installation is, just track down the file in GUI

Comment: thanks again for the response.  so I'm running bash on iterm2.  there's not a space after the "$", it's just that iterm naturally indents that way.  Having said that, I was able to manually cd.. to `~/opt/miniconda3/envs/foo/etc/jupyter/` and found that it contained three files: `jupyter_notebook_config.d`, `nbconfig` & `jupyter_server_config.d`. At least for me, the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file was located in `~/.jupyter/`.  Do you know if that's a problem or should I just edit the file in `~/.jupyter`?

Comment: @jgg okay, thanks for the clarification. If no config file exists already, you can simply create one (either of them) and add the line(s) mentioned. Not sure about the `~/.jupyter/`, but likely can add it there and it would be picked up as well.